# Possible to bind dynamically generated functions to Azure WebJobs JobHost after RunAndBlock called?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

Once I've kicked off a JobHost via RunAndBlock, is it possible to dynamically bind functions to it? I'm specifically interested in doing this using a service bus. I'm envisioning a scenario where the service gets a notification that there's a new type of message available on a particular queue along with the functionality that should get executed when that message is received. It would also be nice to do the reverse - that is to tell a running JobHost to stop handling messages of a specific type. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question, no, you cannot add/bind functions to a running JobHost. All the "listeners" for the various queues, etc. are initialized and started at **startup time only**. All the metadata for what queues to start listening to etc. is determined from compile time metadata on startup. If you'd like, you could make a feature request in our issues list [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues) - it's an interesting (though uncommon) scenario. We are working on something similar to what you ask for in [WebJobs.Script](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script), but this is not core WebJobs SDK. WebJobs.Script defines all host/function metadata in external metadata files. So if a new script + metadata is added (e.g. a function for a new queue) the host will restart itself automatically.

For your second question, check out **DisableAttribute** (see in [Release Notes](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Release-Notes)). It allows you to enable/disable particular functions via application settings. Note that this is also a startup time check, however changes in application settings cause a restart anyways.

Comment: Sad to hear that it isn't possible, but I appreciate the reply. I'll look into making a feature request.